File Details in SharePoint to Rows in Excel
Using "List Folder" > Add Rows in Excel I'm able to populate:

Name of the File
Date Modified

I was curious to add another Column called Link and populate a hyperlink called "Link" for each file that gets populated. I've used hit n trial methods, searched but it's proving to be a waste of time unless someone could point me in the right direction or even a YT video or two!
Get files from a folder in Power Automate is not working was good! I wasn't able to figure out the basics but stuck now.
